# Convert String to variable in PHP inside function argument

Tags: php, function, eval

below is the code I have created. My point here is to convert all strings inside the function argument.

For example, fname('variable1=value1&variable2=value2'); I need to convert variable1 & variable2 into ang variable as $variable1, $variable2 instead parsing a plain text. I found out eval() function is useful but it only takes one string which is the "variable1" and its value.

```
function addFunction($arg){
    echo eval('return $'. $arg . ';');
}
addFunction('variable1=value1&variable2=value2');
```

Now the problem is I got this error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in D:\xampp\htdocs...\index.php(7) : eval()'d code on line 1". But if I have only one variable and value inside the function argument it works perfect, but I need to have more parameters here. Is this possible to do this thing or is there any other way to count the parameters before it can be evaluated?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function addFunction($arg)
{
    parse_str($arg, $args);

    foreach ($args as $key => $val) {
        echo $key , " --> " , $val, "\n";
    }


}

addFunction('variable1=value1&variable2=value2');
```

Output

```
variable1 --> value1
variable2 --> value2
```

You can also use

```
function addFunction($arg)
{
    parse_str($arg);

    echo $variable2; // value2

}

addFunction('variable1=value1&variable2=value2');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a variable with this name:

`$variable1=value1&variable2=value2`

You need to explode it at the `&` to get just the desired future variable names.

```
function addFunction($arg){

    echo eval('return $'. $arg . ';');
}

$string = 'variable1=value1&variable2=value2';

$array = explode('&', $string);

foreach($array as $part)
{
    addFunction($part);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can break a string up using the PHP `explode` function, and then use `eval` to evaluate each variable indepedently.

```
 $myvars = explode ('$', 'variable1=value1&variable2=value2');
```

`$myvars` is then an array which you can parse and feed to `eval` as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use explode()?

```
$varArr = explode("&",$arg);
foreach ($varArr as $varKey=>$varVal) {
    echo eval('return $'.$varKey.'='.$varVal.';');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need split the $arg at & to get each variable and then again at = to get each variable and value.

```
$arg = 'variable1=value1&variable2=value2';
$vars = explode('&', $arg);

foreach ($vars as $var) {
    $parts = explode("=", $var);
    echo eval('return $'. $parts[0] . '='. $parts[1] . ';');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
function addFunction($arg)
{
  $varArr = explode("&",$arg);
  $varResponse ="";

  foreach ($varArr as $varKey=>$varVal) {
   $varResponse = $varResponse."$".$varVal.";";
  }
   return $varResponse;
 }
  echo addFunction('variable1=value1&variable2=value2');
```

Saludos ;)